# Controller for partial view in asp.NET 5 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Iwould like to set a partial View in a form.
The problem is that  I would like this partial View to be controlled by a controller.

Here is the code of the form :

```
<select asp-for="Categorie" id="categorie">
    <partial name="BudgetSearch" />
</select>
```

Here is the code of the controller :

```
public IActionResult BudgetSearch()
    {
        var bdd = new ComptesBudgetViewModel();

        return PartialView(bdd);
    }
```

Here is the code of the partia View :

```
@model Comptes.core.data.DataLayer.HomeDataLayer.ComptesBudgetViewModel

<option value="" selected>Choisir</option>
@foreach (var budget in Model.Budget)
{
    <option value="@budget.Categorie">@budget.Categorie</option>
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: you need to call action that renders your partial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC 5: How do you render a partial view in a div from an action link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233863/asp-net-mvc-5-how-do-you-render-a-partial-view-in-a-div-from-an-action-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enter `Your controller Name` into this code: `load('/ControllerName/BudgetSearch')`

**full code**

```
<select asp-for="Categorie" id="categorie">
     
</select>


@section scripts{
    <script>
       $('#categorie').load('/ControllerName/BudgetSearch');
    </script>
}
```

**And Other Way**

```
public IActionResult MYAction()
{
   var bdd = new ComptesBudgetViewModel();
   return View(bdd);
}
```

**Your View**

```
<select asp-for="Categorie" id="categorie">
    @Html.Partial("BudgetSearch")
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, it's exaclty what I need.

Comment: But, just curiously, does it exist a possibility to do that with c# ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you have to give it a model in the main action.I enter the example in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
/*to load the partial view in main view on click of button*/
$("#btnId").on("click", function () {                          //on button click function using its id
    var suppName = document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;     //to get value of textbox using its id

   /*.get is used to get the partial view having 3 parameter one is url to the partial view
    * 2nd is variable value which you want to pass to controller and same name should be used in controller here in { name: name} 1st name is name should include in controller and 2nd one is variable name
    * 3rd is function to get data in our view #divContaiPopup is the div or place where partial view will be loaded*/
    $.get('@Url.Action("methodNameinController")', { name: name}, function (data) {
        $("#divContaiPopup").html(data);
  });

});



public ActionResult methodNmae(string name)
    {
        var data= new modelClass()
        { 
            modelclass = db.modelname.Where(a=> a.dbTableName.fieldName.Contains(name)).ToList(),
            
        };
        return View("PartialView", data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you, it's a possibility to which I didn't think but it's absolutly interesting, I will jeep it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Html.Action("MyController","BudgetSearch")`, this will call the Controller Action and return the related view inline, some claim its not pure MVC, but I have used it with success before.

Comment: Hello, your answer interest me.
Is it any dll necessary to your solution ?

Comment: Must I set @Html.Action("BudgetSearch") or @Html.Action("Controller/BudgetSearch") ?

Comment: It's not Ok, do I need to add a dll

Comment: No, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Html.Action("") is not supported by .NET Core in my case

Comment: Sorry I just realized you are using .NET Core, you are correct Html.Action is not available: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916664/html-action-in-asp-net-core